# I can't set up pache virtual host on linux

Tags: linux, apache2

To better describe it the thing I wan to set up is:

I have few folders inside `home/USER_NAME/www` htdocs(it's like public_html):

- SITE1 (content of whole site1 pages, images, scripts etc.)
- SITE2 (content of whole site2 pages, images, scripts etc.)
- SITE3 (content of whole site3 pages, images, scripts etc.)
- and a INDEX.HTML with 'HELLO WORLD!'

Now when I type www.site1.com I want that to point out to SITE1 folder inside htdocs. When I type site1.com it should take the data from the web and not from the localhost. Same with SITE2 and SITE3 and so on...

my hosts file looks like:

```
127.0.0.1 www.site1.com
127.0.0.1 www.site2.com
127.0.0.1 www.site3.com
```

so the www prefixed names are correctly redirect.

Right now I set up everything almost correct - when I type www.SITE1.com I get data from index.html and NOT the folder SITE1 - as it supposed to be, and is set in httpd-vhosts.conf file:

```
ServerAdmin lol@lol.com
DocumentRoot "/home/USER_NAME/www/htdocs/SITE1" # <- this is pointing to site1 folder NOT 
    # to "/home/USER_NAME/www/htdocs" where index.html is placed so WTF!? Why is index.html render when going to www.site1.com - 
    # why I need to write www.site1.com/SITE1 to get the content of the site1?
ServerName www.site1.com
ErrorLog "logs/site1a.log"
CustomLog "logs/site1b.log" common
```

Can somebody explain this to me? Do I need to set up a symlink or something? Why httpd-vhosts.conf is not read properly?

Answer (score 0):

The need to set your VirtualHost  and  ServerAlias properties. The ServerAlias  allows to Apache routes the request to the correct web site. If the FQDN doesnt exist you can modify you hosts file in you PC/Client ([Modify Hosts file](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/))

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/example2"
    ServerName www.example.org
    ServerAlias *.example.org
    # ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/example3"
    ServerName www.example.net
    ServerAlias *.example.net
    # ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Documentation: [Apache Doc](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html)